# java- using select statement in java code not being assigned to variable

Tags: java

i have a java program that i am trying to match username and password from a textfield input and compare then with rs list from columns "username" and "password" of that list but it seems as if the variable doesnt get the username and pass passed to it and fails the loop and goes and returns results as false, denying access. i dont understand why it used to work. and why it works if i tried the first tuple in the table (username and pass). below is the code

```
public boolean loginAccount(String username, String password) {
    String dataUsername;
    String dataPassword;
    boolean result = false;

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT Username, Password FROM Accounts";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            dataUsername = rs.getString("Username");
            dataPassword = rs.getString("Password");
            if (username.equals(dataUsername) && password.equals(dataPassword)) {
                result = true;
            } 
        }
        if (result)
            populateAccount(username);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the `while` loop and actually checking whether you do in fact happen upon a username/password combo which matches the input?  Your code looks fine.

Comment: There are several things not quite right here. 1. You shouldn't get all your passwords and then compare in code, rather the sql should have a where clause to only match the password for your username. 2. Unless it is a play project, the password should be encrypted. 3. Why don't you put some debug statements or remote debug this code to see where the problem might be?

Comment: @vsnyc The password should be **hashed.**

Comment: @EJP Yes I agree and salted as well with a unique salt per password to increase complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Few tips...

I hope this has just a fun purpose, cause making a query to a SQL Server downloading the entire Accounts table and performing a while is so BAD practice.

- You transfer an entire table each time someone login
- You perform a string comparison in a Java server with a `While` loop. You have SQL engines that were designed to do so, ad will work faster than what you think.

I will suggest:

- Remove special chars from username and passw string (to avoid SQL injection)
- perform a "SELECT ... WHERE ..." with username and passw stated in the query
- Check if DB reply with more than 0 rows

Another tip: Think about using MD5 for passw (standard practice)

Comment: How/why do you consider MD5 as standard practice?  MD5 is broken.  Sure, play with it 'for fun', but don't use it in enterprise environments.  If you do, you deserve to be hacked.
Standard practice should be SHA-XXX where XXX is a reasonable non-1 number for your application with an additional salt.

Comment: 1. Not MD5, Not SHA-XXX (certainly not SHA-1), but PBKDF2, scrypt or bcrypt. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.
2. You should not count on special character detection to fix SQL injection, and passwords should probably contain special characters, not sure why you would remove them

Comment: Yes, you are totaly right, my lapsus. (either if i still finding  in many old scripts that still running on servers i'm workin on)

Comment: @Tony BenBrahim is there any specific reason? Maybe they are a bit faster in performance. But as far as I know SHA256 (available on any server) still being secure far enought. BitCoin has a 75PHash engine (last time i checked) and there still being noone able to break it.

Comment: @TonyBenBrahim Those are password-based KDFs.  You still need a hash function with that.

Comment: @Blazure, no you generate the derived key and store it along with the salt and # of iterations, when user supplies password, you apply the KDF with the same salt and # of iterations, and compare, same as a hash, but takes much longer (which is the advantage, it is computationally expensive).

Comment: @TheBook Google "SHA-1 NSA" and decide for yourself if you want to trust any variant. I know SHA-256 should be secure, I still use it. The goal of a password "hash" function is to be computationally expensive to avoid brute force attack, and the 3 algos listed (BPKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt) meet that requirement (for example, they cannot be parallelized with GPUs or custom FPGAs).

Comment: but why is this variable,dataUsername = rs.getString("Username"); getting an error saying data value out of context